# How to put reducer inside reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux, reducers

I don't know, what is the correct way how to combine my reducers.

In root reducer I have page reducers like this:

```
export default combineReducers({ 
    guidePage,
    homePage, 
})
```

So, the problem is, that I want to put another reducer into homePage reducer, how can I do this?

Like this:

```
homePage : {
     propHomePage: foo,
     anotherReducer: {
         anotherReducerProp: foo2
     }
}
```

When I use combineReducers({homePage, anotherReducer}) I am getting state like this:

```
{
   homePage: {propHomePage: foo}
   anotherReducer: {anotherReducerProp: foo2}
}
```

And it is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Basically, think of combining reducers as just a key-value object store.

This should work:

```
export default combineReducers({
  guidePage,
  homePage: combineReducers({
    propHomePage,
    anotherReducer
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
const combinedHome = combineReducers({ 
    home1,
    home2, 
})

export default combineReducers({ 
    combinedHome,
    otherReducer, 
})
```